# Difference between TPL and TAP

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to clarify the difference between two these abbreviations: `TPL`(a task parallel library) and `TAP` (task async pattern).

AFAIU, `TPL` - is a task parallel library and the main part of this library is `Task` and all related staff. So, it's like a technology which was implemented by `Microsoft`.

`TAP` - it's a pattern which underlies to `async`/`await` syntax sugar. And which is based on `callback` function  + `state machine` + `SynchronizationContext` logic.

Is there something to add or correct?

Answer (score 11):

TPL is a part of the BCL. It includes `Task` as well as several other parallelism-related higher-level abstractions including `Parallel` and Parallel LINQ. The focus of TPL was parallel processing, and using tasks as futures - while supported - was a relatively unused feature.

TAP is a pattern. It's called "Task-based" because it reused the `Task` type from the TPL as a generic Future type. `Task` (and related types) were enhanced to include more primitives to support TAP and asynchronous programming (e.g., `GetAwaiter()`, `Task.WhenAll`, etc). These days, TAP also works with "tasklikes" including `ValueTask`. TAP is focused on asynchronous programming as opposed to parallel processing.